# How should I access Boost SHA1 hash?

Tags: c++, boost, sha1

I want to use `boost::uuids::detail::sha1` to create a hash for a large binary blob.

See: [boost uuid sha1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp)

`sha1` is in the `detail` namespace and as such should not be 'relied upon'. How can I create the SHA1 hash for my blob without instantiating objects in `detail`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your choices are:

- Use `boost::uuids::detail::sha1`, and if it changes in a future release, deal with it then.
- Find another implementation of sha1 (say in Crypto++, for example), and use that.